# Compilation variables declaration and usage in .net core

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, oracle-wallet

How to write compilation variable for oracle and oracle wallet in .Net Core?

Example:

```
if (oracle) 
{
oracle namespace
}
else if (oracle wallet) 
{
oracle wallet namespace
}
```

Comment: Consider using the [Strategy Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern).